# Which of XYZM-coordinates match the result of grids algorithm in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, csv, import, grids-graticules

When you create a grid in QGIS, in the attribute table for each square, you have a corresponding column left, right, top, bottom in coordinates. Which of these four correspond to the X, Y, Z, M coordinates?

I am trying to import a grid from a CSV file with the left, right, top, bottom columns. I had to export the grid because I couldn't figure out how to add the values from multiple columns correctly in the field calculator in QGIS. So I exported it into a CSV, added the columns in Excel, now I want to bring the file back into QGIS.

Alternatively, how do I create a new column in the attribute table that adds the values in multiple columns by using the field calculator? I tried `"Col1"+"Col2"+"Col3"` and `sum(col1,col2,col3)` but couldn't get completely correct values for some reason. In the first case it only seemed to be adding some of the columns.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Create a grid from "Create grid" tool? Left and right is X, Top and bottom Y.

Comment: We definitely need more details. Currently any attempt to answering is just wild guessing, since we don't know, how your csv exactly looks etc.

Comment: Added pictures of attribute table and grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly saying there is **no match**, but you can make some of it yourself.

The resulting Attribute table after using the [**Create Grid**](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html?#create-grid) contains five fields, namely: 
 `"id"`, `"left"`, `"top"`, `"right"`, and `"bottom"`, see an image below.

[image: example]

*where:*

- `"id"` is simply an integer starting from 1 until n-th cell. The
  order of cells is from the top-left feature to the bottom left each time moving one column right an so on, something like following the *`И`*-pattern.
- `"left"` corresponds to the most western `"X"`-coordinate
- `"top"`  to the most northern `"Y"`-coordinate
- `"right"` to the most eastern `"X"`-coordinate
- `"bottom"` to the most southern `"Y"`-coordinate

[image: coordinates]

If your question was interpreted correctly, there are several possibilities to get the coordinates for each cell.

1. Coordinates as a centroid of each cell:

```sql
SELECT "id", ST_X(st_centroid(geometry)) AS "X", ST_Y(st_centroid(geometry)) AS "Y"
FROM "Grid"
```

[image: case_1]

2. Coordinates as a centroid of each cell in WKT-format:

```sql
SELECT "id", st_astext(st_centroid(geometry))
FROM "Grid"
```

[image: case_2]

3. Coordinates as a polyline in WKT-format:

```sql
SELECT "id", st_astext(st_exteriorring(geometry))
FROM "Grid"
```

[image: case_3]

4. Coordinates as a polygon in WKT-format:

```sql
SELECT "id", st_astext(geometry)
FROM "Grid"
```

[image: case_4]

All Options are based on the usage of a *Virtual Layer* through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

So, my suggestion on this stage before exporting a grid in CSV-file  is to create a new column in the Attribute table where you will store the geometry in a WKT-Format i.e. in the Field calculator use `geom_to_wkt($geometry)` for a text-field with unlimited length, see image below.

[image: geom_wkt]

So, afterwards you will be able freely read the wkt-geometry when importing a CSV-file into QGIS-Project, part of in described here [Loading WKT polygons into QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202770/loading-wkt-polygons-into-qgis/202772).

If suddenly you have no opportunity to read a WKT from a CSV-file in QGIS, put eye on the following workflow.

1. Drag&Drop your csv with grids into QGIS

   [image: csv_in_qgis]
2. Deploy a *Virtual Layer* through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` to obtain a layer with geometry.

```sql
SELECT *, setsrid(make_polygon(make_line(
                                    make_point(left,bottom),
                                    make_point(left,top),
                                    make_point(right,top),
                                    make_point(right,bottom)
                                )), #here use your SRID, e.g. 25833)    
FROM "test"
```

3. Get the Output

   [image: result]

Regarding the `"Z"` and `"M"` coordinates. If you have those Attributes in you CSV-file then extend the `make_point(left,bottom)` to `make_point(left,bottom, "alltitude_field", "m_field")`, e.g. `make_point(1,2,3,4)`, as described in [PostGIS Docs | ST_MakePoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html).

Comment: I knew that the LRTB columns corresponded to the sides of each grid cell, but I am assuming the code you gave will help build a better CSV for re-import. Will try soon